# {underscore.js} First name is before its last name alphabetically

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Method that from a given array of students finds all students whose first name is before its last name alphabetically.
Print the students in descending order by full name.
I must use Underscore.js
plz help

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried and some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wrC3/6/)**

```
// Initialize students array.
var students = [ {
    firstname: 'Sachin',
    secondname: 'Tendulkar'
}, {
    firstname: 'Sourav',
    secondname: 'Ganguly'
}, {
    firstname: 'Rahul',
    secondname: 'Dravid'
}, {
    firstname: 'Virat',
    secondname: 'Kohli'
}, {
    firstname: 'Rohit',
    secondname: 'Sharma'
}];

// Filter students whose firstname is before secondname.
var testStudents = _.filter(students, function(student){
    return student.firstname < student.secondname;
});

// Sorted the array in asc order.
testStudents = _.sortBy(testStudents, function(student){
    return student.firstname + ' ' + student.secondname;
});

// Reverse the array.
testStudents = testStudents.reverse();

// Log the result.
console.log(testStudents);
```